# Adding custom menu item to ToolStripMenuItem's collection list

Tags: vb.net, toolstripmenu, toolstripitem

I'm building my own ToolStripMenuItem and I want it to show up in the list of choices to add to a Menu's DropDownItems collection. How do I do that?

Here's what I have so far.

```
imports System.ComponentModel

''' <summary>
''' A list of check box items that remember which item is currently checked
''' </summary>
public class ToolStripCheckItemList : inherits ToolStripMenuItem
    private itemsList as List(of Object)

    event checkedItemChanged(sender as Object, e as EventArgs)

    <Category("Items"), _
        Description("The list of items contained in the check list.")>
    public property items() as List(of Object)
    set

    End Set
    Get
        return itemsList
    End Get
    End Property
end class
```

Comment: What do you have so far? Consider adding some code to your question and also a screenshot illustrating what you have vs what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Not a whole lot considering I want to make sure I can see this thing in Visual Studio's Toolbox, but if you insist with a -1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the attribute I needed. I put it right above my class name.

```
<ToolStripItemDesignerAvailabilityAttribute(ToolStripItemDesignerAvailability.MenuStrip)>
```